# Make Command-History Pop-Up work via F7 in Windows 10 Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

In a Powershell console, on Windows 10 (10.0.17134.0), F7 does not pop-up the Command History like it does for CMD console. How could we make this work in a PS console window?  Any hints on a `$Profile` syntax to do so?

Comment: I'd simply use `ghy`

Comment: There is only one Windows console (conhost.exe), not a PowerShell console vs a CMD console. The console's built-in command-line editing and history is available with high-level cooked reads, i.e. `ReadConsole` or `ReadFile`. An application can instead use low-level `ReadConsoleInput` to take complete control over command-line editing and history, which PowerShell does by default because this lets it save and reload history across sessions.

Comment: I was referring to the more high level thing - the Window that opens when you execute the `powershell.exe` application.

Comment: https://github.com/omniomi/AdvancedHistory

Comment: See https://github.com/gui-cs/F7History

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one work around is: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4x5iig/f7_history_no_longer_in_windows_10_au/.

Run `Remove-Module -Name PSReadLine` from the command-line.  It will remove the `PSReadLine` module from *that session*.  That let's F7 work again to display the history.

Comment: I don't recommend this solution because it disables all `PSReadline` module goodness and reverts to standard console input features.

Comment: Glad to get a separate perspective.  How would I wire your cmdlet such that it would execute every time I start a Powershell shell?

Comment: Add it to your profile script.

Answer (score 19):

As you discovered, this is because the PSReadline module is installed by default on Windows 10. You can add your own <kbd>F7</kbd> in PSReadline by using the `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler` cmdlet in a script. Example:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key F7 -BriefDescription "History" -LongDescription "Show command history" -ScriptBlock {
  $pattern = $null
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref] $pattern, [ref] $null)
  if ( $pattern ) {
    $pattern = [Regex]::Escape($pattern)
  }
  $history = [System.Collections.ArrayList] @(
    $last = ""
    $lines = ""
    foreach ( $line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath) ) {
      if ( $line.EndsWith('`') ) {
        $line = $line.Substring(0, $line.Length - 1)
        $lines = if ( $lines ) { "$lines`n$line" } else { $line }
        continue
      }
      if ( $lines ) {
        $line = "$lines`n$line"
        $lines = ""
      }
      if ( ($line -cne $last) -and ((-not $pattern) -or ($line -match $pattern)) ) {
        $last = $line
        $line
      }
    }
  )
  $command = $history | Out-GridView -Title History -PassThru
  if ( $command ) {
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::RevertLine()
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert(($command -join "`n"))
  }
}
```

When you use this function, the <kbd>F7</kbd> key will appear in a pop-up grid view window. Select a history entry and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and PowerShell will put it on the command line for editing.

Comment: [System.IO.File]::ReadLines could be simplified by get-content

Comment: This is an AMAZING answer!

Comment: Now, with the PowerShell GraphicalTools `Out-ConsoleGridView` you can do this:  https://gist.github.com/tig/cbbeab7f53efd73e329afd6d4b838191

Comment: just getting into powershell (v7) since 4 weeks and I concur with crimbo, this was an AMAZING answer.  Thank you @Bill_Stewart

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376858/windows-10-powershell-f7-broken#comment87770201_50376858)'s comment above, you can also run commands from running `ghy` (a.k.a `Get-History` or just `h`) using `ihy` (a.k.a `Invoke-History` or just `r`)